# Python openpyxl Excel not recognizing saved file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've been trying to create a basic Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl and it's not working.

My code is as follows:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
sheet['A1'] = 'Hello'
sheet['B1'] = 'World!'

filepath = 'C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Programming Projects/Excel Stuff/test.xlsx'
workbook.save(filepath)
```

The program creates a document in the filepath where I want it, but it creates some kind of weird document that won't open in Excel.

The symbol is just a sheet of paper, and in the folder it says it's an XSLX file, and it has a size of 5KB, but it's just kind of a nothing document. Can't even open it with a text editor.

I have no idea how to fix this.

*****Edit: I tried all of your solutions and it still didn't work. I think the problem lies not in the code, but somewhere in my computer itself.

Comment: You should not expect to be able to open can `.xlsx` file in a text editor. It's essentially a zipfile.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! The problem was that I was running python as an administrator. Somehow that broke the program.

Answer (score -1):

I've just tested your code with a small change about the directory.

Code works fine, flie was created and python code works flawlessly.

[image]

The only thing I can think about is changing the filepath to a raw string:

```
filepath = r'C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Programming Projects/Excel Stuff/test.xlsx'
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is my computer then, somehow